# Proving that $y^2=x^3-6$ has no integer solutions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ were a solution to $y^2=x^3-6$

Prove that there exists a principal ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$ such that $(y+\sqrt{-6})=\mathfrak{a}^3$.

I have no idea what to do for this part of the proof.

Comment: Can someone please fix the misspelling in the heading? There's got to be a way to do that without triggering the reopen question process.

Answer (score 3):

This is Theorem $2.3$ of this very nice [article](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf) by Keith Conrad. The proof is quite elementary and starts by rewriting $y^2=x^3-6$ by
$$
y^2 - 2 = x^3- 8 = (x- 2)(x^2 + 2x + 4).
$$